# Android map works on API 19 but not on API 22

Tags: android, google-maps

I have Android application which i developed several months on my device which works on API 19. Now when i got new phone with API 22 all works except the Google map. Is there something special with Google maps on this API or am i doing something wrong? In the application setting i have

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    //tried this but still wont work    
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'     
}
```

Code for map activity is and i have comment // where error happens

```
public class MapLocation extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
public Double lat;
public Double log;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_location);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    lat = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat"));
    log = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("log"));
    centerMapOnMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if (mMap == null) {

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
               .getMap();            
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);        
}
private void centerMapOnMyLocation() {

    //HERE is ERROR when checking log of phone
    //HERE is ERROR when checking log of phone
    //HERE is ERROR when checking log of phone
    //HERE is ERROR when checking log of phone


    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    if (!(lat == 0.0 || log == 0.0)) {

        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18);

        CameraUpdate myLocation= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,log));

        mMap.moveCamera(myLocation);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, log)).title("Title"));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map positioned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "no location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Log of phone

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smth/com.smth.MapLocation}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
>                                                          at com.smth.MapLocation.centerMapOnMyLocation(MapLocation.java:83)
>                                                          at com.vodovod.ivan.watercounter.MapLocation.onCreate(MapLocation.java:30)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6036)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Layout of map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:keepScreenOn="true">
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
 tools:context="com.vodovod.ivan.watercounter.MapLocation"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
 android:keepScreenOn="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Map is not inmediately available for you to use, that is why it says you are calling on a null object. Override onMapReady method, and call setMyLocationEnabled in that method.

Comment: I can't override that method. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, you need to implement OnMapReadyCallback interface

Comment: Follow Documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_6_connect_an_android_device for maps

Comment: Thanks for help @Fustigador. Can you explain me why then API 19 didn't had problems with that? And post your comment as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help. Answering your question, I can only guess that API 19 does less things, and because of that the process maybe is faster. But it is only a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map is not inmediately available for you to use, that is why it says you are calling on a null object. Implement OnMapReadyCallback interface, override onMapReady method from that interface, and call methods involving Google Map instance inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Fustigador, you get a NullPointerException because the map object is not yet initialized. To solve your problem, replace `getMap()` with

```
getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                centerMapOnMyLocation(map);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Exactly what I said.